# How to give write permission to SD card in android ?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am unable to give write permission to the SD card. I am using robotium and i want to save the screen shots. By default robotium saves it in SD card. 
I have given write and read permission in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Re-mounting the sd card is not changing the permission.I am using andorid 4.4

This is the log message :

```
01-24 01:35:39.346: D/Robotium(4252): Can't save the screenshot! Requires write permission (android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) in AndroidManifest.xml of the application under test.
```

I have gone through all posts related to this. But nothing fruitful happened.

Comment: clean your project and test again, and if you test on real device first uninstall then after clean test again

Comment: check for USB debugging option in u r device... try to clean and rebuild u r project

Comment: I'm 99% sure, you set it in test project, not in application project